# Adding internal testers to TestFlight not working - email not sent

Tags: ios, testflight

I am trying to add new users to my Users and Roles in iTune Connect. I go through the steps, assigning them as Technical/Admin, and hit the Add button.

I get the confirmation on the dashboard that they have been sent a verification email... but it seems nothing is being sent!! And as a result I cannot add them to the Internal testers list.

Is there a reason why verification emails are not being sent to new users being added?

Cheer
AF

Comment: I am having the same issue here, I didn't receive the internal tester invitation email, so I removed the user entirely from users & roles and re-add the user but now I didn't even  receive the verification email..

Comment: Yeah i had this issue at one stage with a particular user which was on my internal testers list. But on this occassion I am not even getting into the stage of having the new user on the list

Answer (score 1):

iTC TestFlight has been notorious for dropping emails.  Apple has also been having outages recently related to iTC (as well as other systems).  The only thing you can do is remove the user and later re-add them - that will trigger the invite email again, and if iTC is working properly at the time they'll get the email.

You might also want to reach out to support so they can see if there is anything going on with your account.  I had to do this for an iTC issue last week...and I heard back a week later that the issue was resolved.

Good luck!